# JavaScript Mocha initial integration test takes longer than others

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mocha.js

The initial `test` for each `test.spec.js` takes longer than others and sometimes times out.

I'm testing against `MySQL` database using `Sequelize`.

Any insight?

Comment: Is it on the local setup?

Comment: Do you mean the database? If so, yes it is local to machine and the tests

Comment: Heavy data transfer between test and MySql?

Comment: No, 25 records and one of the first test is to get a single row in the database.

Comment: Have you checked the database manually, How much time it takes independently?